# How to extend ubuntu partition size?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Ok, so `dev/sda1` is empty now, but it had Windows XP installed there. `dev/sda5` is Ubuntu. I want to delete `dev/sda1` and extend `dev/sda5`. In GParted LiveCD, when I delete `dev/sda1` and try to resize `dev/sda5` it won't allow me to do that. So how do I do that?

[image: Gparted]

Comment: You have to do it from LiveCD, because the partition has to be unmounted.

Comment: I did, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your photo that all partitions are mounted. (the key icon)
sda5 placed within the extended partition sda2.
You must resize sda2 first.

Comment: In GParted LiveCD, when I delete dev/sda1 and try to resize dev/sda5 it won't allow me to do that.

Comment: Did you resize sda2 after deleting sda1?

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative:

- [convert sda5 from ext4 to btrfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs#Converting_Ubuntu_12.10_ext4_root_filesystem), or (better) reinstall Ubuntu choosing "Something else.." and formatting sda5 to btrfs
- convert (or reformat) sda1 to btrfs (which is simpler: just do `btrfs-convert /dev/sda1`)
- mount (or boot) sda5, and run in a terminal: `sudo btrfs device add /dev/sda1 /path/of/sda5` (which is `/` if you boot).

Ubuntu will now span over two devices. Remember to make a backup first.